# Built in "High Contrast" mode for websites to meet accessibility standards?

Tags: accessibility, high-contrast

I've been working on a few websites that have beautiful color palettes but do not provide high enough contrast between text and background for accessibility. I love to make sites usable for everyone, but as a designer, I feel bummed that so many awesome color combinations are totally off the table. Would providing an obvious way to toggle into a high contrast mode be an acceptable alternative?

Comment: Larger sites do an Accessibility Mode, eg. Salesforce, but it's more around function rather than design. I feel your pain, I as a designer want to do more complex things with colour but especially in the States it's important to meet WCAG standards or larger sites face federal and state penalties for not complying. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=accessibility_overview.htm&type=5

Comment: Not sure where you are in the design process, but to partly answer your question, a website should at least meet [WCAG 2.1 standards](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/%23contrast-minimum) for [text contrast](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/%23contrast-minimum#contrast-minimum) and [non-text contrast **](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/%23contrast-minimum#non-text-contrast) without** enabling high contrast.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of users would benefit from a high-contrast color scheme, including many who don't regard themselves as disabled. You can certainly let yourself off-the-hook, legally speaking by providing a WCAG compliant color scheme alongside whatever awesome swatch you prefer. I would advise starting with the WCAG-compliant one first, and make it the default, so you always have that as a base to fall back on.

You could even use the forced-colors media query, although this is not yet standard. There are a few other related media queries offered by Microsoft, as mentioned here
https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2020/09/17/styling-for-windows-high-contrast-with-new-standards-for-forced-colors/

But before you start working on a new color scheme, it will be more worth checking how your 'regular' site looks like with some of the system-level contrast mode settings enabled. These are available on most platforms, and there are a number of browser extensions which also manipulate color/contrast (each works slightly differently).

Please note that it's perfectly possible to make the UI unusable using system level "high contrast" features with 'extreme' settings. Mac OS's contrast slider can almost bleach out the entire screen if pushed to the edge! I can't help wondering who this is supposed to benefit.

**WCAG does not require that content should be perceivable within the broad limits of every single high contrast gadget on the market**, so in general, if these kinds of problem only occur when the gadget is enabled, they are not (strictly) WCAG violations.

However, given that the success criteria "Focus Visible", "Text Contrast" and "Non-Text Contrast" are already met, any contrast "failures" which only occur when High Contrast gadgets are enabled are usually best understood as *possible* violations of [SC 1.3.1 Info and Relationships](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/info-and-relationships), because they do not "ensure that information and relationships that are implied by visual formatting are preserved when the presentation format changes". You might also have some violations of [SC 1.4.1 Use of Color](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/use-of-color) if any distinctions are made by color alone. (e.g. if all headings are the same font and size as body text, but in red).

Therefore the important thing is to try your content with some of the default schemes in (say) Windows High Contrast Mode. Check that everything is still distinguishable, especially including focus indicators and UI states (e.g. text labels, disabled controls, checkboxes and radiobuttons, thumbs on sliders and scrollbars, data views etc.). It will probably not be very beautiful, but that's not the point. Again, it's **not** a WCAG violation if you don't offer perfection in Windows High Contrast Mode, although you should probably mention any howlers in any Accessibility Conformance Report or VPAT.

As a small tip, I will mention that Windows High Contrast Mode will try to color-code UI borders to reflect certain states. (e.g. a button with a disabled attribute might be drawn with a green border). Therefore: Make sure your UI controls have borders of at least 1px. If you don't want a visible border in the regular scheme, use a transparent color. Similarly, make sure any non-decorative SVG content uses some kind of stroke to be distinguishable in Windows HCM.

That way, if someone enables HCM, the boundaries of content, and also the state of the controls will still be perceivable.